# Interior design Stack Exchange site

Tags: feature-request, area-51

I am wondering if there are any people out there also wondering why there isn't any Stack Exchange website for [interior designers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_design). The [DIY](http://diy.stackexchange.com) is more DIY contracting-based and is for technical-driven questions.

Comment: I think the "answers" to such questions would be far too opinionated for the Stack Exchange model of websites.

Comment: [You're not alone](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/50843/interior-design) - Area51 is the place to propose new sites, not Meta.

Comment: Thanks, will ask there. Can I move my question?

Comment: @csh there's nothing to move.  You asked about an interior design site and Mat shows your that there is one proposed.  Feel free to support it and help the proposal evolve into a real site

Comment: @psubsee2003 Gotcha

Comment: Proposal died; I assume because of @TronicZomB 's reasoning.  I suppose there's always Houzz.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Stack Exchange sites are developed through the http://area51.stackexchange.com site. There is a process outlined there for starting a new SE site.

Basically there is no Interior Design site because one has not developed a sufficient audience to start.

If you are interested in starting one there is a proposal you can join here:

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/50843/interior-design